# Translation for a few sentences which sound strange to me

Tags: translation, english-to-german

I need to translate a few more sentences into the complicated German language. And your feedback would be incredibly awesome!

1. Do you currently have a UK address? / Haben Sie derzeit eine UK-Adresse?
2. Do you have a Care of or a Hold mail address in US? / Haben Sie eine Pflege oder eine Hold-Mail-Adresse in den US?
3. Do you give any SO instruction to transfer money to an account in US? / Geben Sie jede SO Anweisung Geld auf ein Konto in den USA zu übertragen?
4. Did you give a power of attorney to authorized person who has address in UK? / Hast du eine Vollmacht an autorisierte Person, die Adresse in der UK hat?
5. Do you currently have a telephone number in the UK? / Sie haben zur Zeit eine Telefonnummer in den UK?

Many thanks,

Emms

Comment: Please don't spam this Stack Exchange with translation or proofreading questions like that. One was okay, but this is too much.

Comment: Welcome to the German Language SE. Unfortunately, just like your other question, this new question is off-topic. Please compare http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/a/921/15481 . For further information, please take a look around the [help]. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do you currently have a UK address?
> Haben Sie derzeit eine Adresse im Vereinigten Königreich?
>
> Do you have a Care of or a Hold mail address in US?
> Haben Sie eine Ersatzzustellungs- oder Bleibepostvereinbarung in den Vereinigten Staaten?
>
> Do you give any SO instruction to transfer money to an account in US?
> Haben Sie einen Dauerauftrag zur Überweisung von Geld an ein US-Konto?
>
> Did you give a power of attorney to authorized person who has address in UK?
> Haben Sie einer Person mit Adresse im Vereinigten Königreich eine Handlungsvollmacht erteilt?
>
> Do you currently have a telephone number in the UK?
> Haben Sie zur Zeit eine Telefonnummer im Vereinigten Königreich?

Comment: Please consider not answering questions that are obviously off topic. See also https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/133552/

Comment: @hiergiltdiestfu I considered this, but as the OP showed some minimal amount of effort I thought I might try to help this time.

Comment: Btw, bad "minimal amounts of efforts" would, if not under _no translation service_, still be OT unter _no proofreading service_. I'll stop now, promised ;)

Comment: Thanks for the help, Thorsten! I really appreciate the positive attitude and the time you have spent (a lot or a little, it doesn't matter to me).

Comment: I did not know I cannot ask for proofreading a few sentences - my sincere apologies. As I did not receive a comment for the first question to make me believe it was a problem, I posted my second question.

Comment: @EmmaZ yeah, it was a timing problem in both cases. The answer and you seeing it happened much quicker than your questions getting closed because for closing, 5 users are needed to decide if your Q really is off-topic. I'm happy for you personally that you got quick help, don't get me wrong. It's just that the SE Q&A is inteded for posteriority, too, and thus, some selection process has to be applied to the posts, to keep overall quality appreciable.

Comment: @EmmaZ some users have taken to [chat] to get answers for questions that do not reach the on-topic threshold. Participating in chat is possible as soon as you've collected 20 "rep" points.

Comment: @hiergiltdiestfu I agree with you with this question being off-topic, really, but then again, there are so many questions here that come to translation/proof-reading without being closed...

Comment: And _that_, my fellow stack exchanger, is the Broken Window Effect. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broken_windows_theory

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar thanks again for your effort. It was timely and appreciated (and used!).